# How to add sidebar

Tags: taskbar

I have installed Ubuntu desktop on my new Raspi 5 and when I finish setup, I'm just taken to the home screen with nothing on it, just the time and date. I was wondering how to add a taskbar/sidebar to it.

EDIT: just thought to say, I've tried installing it twice and nothing different happened either time.

Comment: First of all, have you tried bumping the cursor over against the left edge of the screen to possibly show the side bar launcher? Also, is the ubuntu-desktop installed: `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`? If this does install packages, you'll probably have to log out and then select the Ubuntu Desktop from a menu selection on the login screen before you log in.

Comment: @mchid I have tried bumping the mouse on the left, and I can't access terminal either.